# Is there a good method to link an account as a resource to a Jenkins test?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Trying to set up some automation testing to run on Jenkins, but the tests need an account linked to it in order to pass successfully.

The method to do so would provide the job with either a label that links to an account or tells the job that the account is not available right now. The method would also have to have a way to make the account available when the job is finished, or give up the account when a job crashes or aborts before it finishes.

I read about Lockable Resources and External Resource Dispatcher and was wondering if anyone had used either of these in a way similar to what I described above or if there is another plugin that could do what I need to do.